# IPSEC VPN to secondary router with additional remote network

Tags: router, vpn, pfsense, ipsec

Our SITE A router/firewall is PFSense.
SITE A Has a LAN of 10.2.1.0/24 with an IPSEC tunnel up between that and cellular router with a LAN of 192.168.182.46.  This is connected to the customers gateway of 192.168.182.254 with an additonal local subnet behind it of 192.168.180.0/24.

The tunnel is up and passing traffic between the two VPN endpoints, but traffic is not routing to the 192.168.180.0/24 subnet.  The cellular router is able to ping and receive responses locally from the 192.168.180.0/25 subnet.

I've confirmed the firewall is not blocking traffic through extensive monkeying around and wireshark logs.

I don't have access to the clients SITE B router for configuration changes.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsAw9.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Drawing linked below.

Comment: Your cellular router would likely have a double NAT. Might that be the issue?  And can you use a different router there?  Maybe a VPN router that can bring traffic in and send it out?